# how to run a command as Administrator mode

Tags: postgresql, batch-file

I have batch file i.e test.bat . I need to run a command of postgresql  as Administrator mode.
Basically the command is for to set password for postgres.
I tried

**C:/Users/pathfinder> runas /user:Administrator net user postgres postgres**

But its not working out.

Comment: You'll have to try and explain what you want to achieve - the above command doesn't seem to run anything as far as I can see. Are you trying to start the PostgreSQL server as Administrator, or run some SQL as the "postgres" user?

Comment: @RichardHuxton : i want to set password for postgres.

Comment: Are you talking about the postgres **Windows** user, or the postgres **database** user? Also: since 9.2 no special postgres *Windows* user is needed to run the service

Answer (score 1):

I tried this code. Its working if i directly run the batch file i.e test.exe but if i configure this file into Advanced installer and run through .exe file its going into indefinite loop of terminals opening.

Just add these codes at the starting of your batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF

:: BatchGotAdmin
:-------------------------------------
REM  --> Check for permissions
>nul 2>&1 "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\cacls.exe" "%SYSTEMROOT%\system32\config\system"

REM --> If error flag set, we do not have admin.
if '%errorlevel%' NEQ '0' (
    echo Requesting administrative privileges...
    goto UACPrompt
) else ( goto gotAdmin )



:UACPrompt
    echo Set UAC = CreateObject^("Shell.Application"^) > "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    echo UAC.ShellExecute "%~s0", "", "", "runas", 1 >> "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"


    "%temp%\getadmin.vbs"
    exit /B


:gotAdmin
    if exist "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" ( del "%temp%\getadmin.vbs" )
    pushd "%CD%"

    CD /D "%~dp0"
```

And write your batch file script just below of the above code.
It will help you to execute a command as Administrator.